# Не работает команда cd../ в shell- клиент

Tags: shell

Всем привет. Есть свой сервер
Нужно запустить веб сокет, для начало делал так cd../ но выдает ошибку что такой дериктории не существует. После этого я вбивал

```
cd var/www/www-root/data/www/reallot.kz/application/third_party
ws_service.js pm2 star
```

И нормально работало, но пишит везде не может найти директорию Принтскрин приложил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему точка вместо пробела? Попробуй cd /

Answer (score 0):

Пробел ставьте после `cd`:

```
cd ..
```

или

```
cd /
```

непонятно что вы конкретно хотите, но что-то из этого явно.